# Run python kivy application in "kiosk mode"

Tags: kivy, raspbian, python-2.x, kiosk-mode

I've created a simple python application running in raspbian using kivy. The application runs already nicely in full screen mode. however I would like to be sure it cannot be interrupted with ctrl-c or any other command using the keyboard, and the application must never lose focus if something happens in the OS (for example some kind of dialog opens - I'm not sure if this actually can happen). I'd appreciate things that should be taken care of.

My app doesn't need to be bullet-proof, but it should endure a "casual user".

Answer (score 1):

You can catch Ctrl+c or other signals with the signal module.

```
import signal
    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        pass
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

This code prevent the user to exit by sending the SIGINT signal, corresponding to ctrl + c.
Other signals: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals

Comment: Thanks, this does inded catch the signal, but for some reason it still also quits the program in Raspbian.